# How to apply MLFlow prediction model in a stream?

Tags: python, spark-streaming, databricks, spark-structured-streaming

I have a stream that reads ready to post feature data into an already registered model. All code is in Python. The following model and meta data function outside of stream in a regular notebook. In stream is another matter. The main issue is the data written out of stream (into destination table) has a NULL prediction. The other thing is the `foreachBatch` function seems unresponsive, even to deliberately planted syntax errors. No signs its a problem in the logs or the in the notebook feedback. It is as if its not being called.

I realise I am writing to the table twice (once in the function and once in the `writeStream`. Only one record makes it and its from the `writeStream` - not the function.

Code is below:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
from pyspark.sql.functions import split

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("MyTest") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Create a streaming DataFrame
lines = spark.readStream \
    .format("delta") \
    .option('ignoreDeletes','true') \
    .table("schema.transformeddata") 

fixedValueStream = lines.select('feature1','feature2', 'feature3')


# Split the lines into words
def batchpredictions(df, epoch_id):
    
    pyfunc_udf = mlflow.pyfunc.spark_udf(spark, model_uri='runs:/<myrunid>/model')
    prediction = df.withColumn("prediction", pyfunc_udf(struct('feature1','feature2','feature3')))
    prediction.write.mode("append").saveAsTable("schema.transformeddata_prediction")
    

fixedValueStream.writeStream.format("delta").outputMode("append").foreachBatch(batchpredictions).option("checkpointLocation", "/delta/events/_checkpoints/etl-from-json").table("schema.transformeddata_prediction")
```

Incoming data :

```
feature1, feature2, feature3
1       , 5       , 9
2       , 6       , 10
3       , 7       , 11
4       , 8       , 12
```

Outgoing data

```
feature1, feature2, feature3, prediction
1       , 5       , 9       , NULL
2       , 6       , 10      , NULL
3       , 7       , 11      , NULL
4       , 8       , 12      , NULL
```

Any clues to what I am doing wrong?

***UPDATE:** Thank you to Mike for your responses. I aim to begin optimizing my solution below using some of the things you've suggested. For now I merely needed to get something to work to fall back on. The solution in its current state is below.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import mlflow
import mlflow.xgboost
import xgboost
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.types import *

# Load model as a PysparkUDF
loaded_model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model('runs:/<mymodelrunid>/model')

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("MyTest") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Create a streaming DataFrame
lines = spark.readStream \
    .format("delta") \
    .option('ignoreDeletes','true') \
    .table("<myschema>.<mytableinput>") 
    
fixedValueStream = lines.select('feature1','feature2', 'feature3', 'feature4', 'feature5')

def foreach_batch_function(df, epoch_id):
    #text value of the multi class prediction GREEN, RED, BLUE
    df = df.withColumn("pred_class", lit('    '))
    
    #Prepare 3 holders for the 3 class scores returned from multiclass model. 
    #Done before hand so I don't have to deal with data type/additional column index/key issues.
    df = df.withColumn("prediction_class1", lit(0.00).cast("double"))
    df = df.withColumn("prediction_class2", lit(0.00).cast("double"))
    df = df.withColumn("prediction_class3", lit(0.00).cast("double"))
    
    #Select back into pandas frame
    pd_df = df.select('feature1','feature2', 'feature3', 'feature4', 'feature5','pred_class','prediction_class1','prediction_class2','prediction_class3').toPandas()

    #Pass pandas frame into model and return array of shape [<batch-df-rows-count>][3]
    y_pred = loaded_model.predict(pd_df)
    
    #Retun the max column score
    predicted_idx = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
    
    #Translate said column into end user labels 
    y_pred_class = np.where(predicted_idx == 1, 'GREEN', np.where(predicted_idx == 0, 'RED', 'BLUE' ))
    
    #Assign class to place holder column
    pd_df["pred_class"] = y_pred_class

    #Store the 3 prediction strengths into place holder columns
    pd_df["prediction_class1"] = y_pred[:,0]
    pd_df["prediction_class2"] = y_pred[:,1]
    pd_df["prediction_class3"] = y_pred[:,2]
    
    #Write out back to a monitoring table
    result = spark.createDataFrame(pd_df)
    result.write.option("mergeSchema","true").format("delta").option("header", "true").mode("append").saveAsTable("<myschema>.<mytableoutput>")
    
#write stream out
fixedValueStream.writeStream.foreachBatch(foreach_batch_function).start()
```

Comment: why do you need to use `foreachBatch`? why not just apply spark UDF to the stream?

Comment: Thanks, I am working through the responses today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @AlexOtt pointed out in the comments there is no need to apply `foreachBatch` as far as your question is currently written.

All you need to do it applying the UDF to your streaming Dataframe using `withColumn`.

---

In case you do need to use `foreachBatch`, maybe because you are writing out to a non-streamable sink format you can read below how to do it.

Looking at the documentation on `foreachBatch` in the [Structured Streaming Programming Guidelines](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach-and-foreachbatch), you do not need a `format` and a `outputMode` in your final writeStream. Instead, the logic where the data is written to is defined within the foreachBatch function. Also, using `saveAsTable` in a stream also does not look right.

Overall, your code shoule look like:

```py
def batchpredictions(df, epoch_id):
    # Split the lines into words
    pyfunc_udf = mlflow.pyfunc.spark_udf(spark, model_uri='runs:/<myrunid>/model')
    prediction = df.withColumn("prediction", pyfunc_udf(struct('feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3')))
    prediction.write.mode("append").format("delta").save("/tmp/delta-table")
    

fixedValueStream.writeStream.foreachBatch(batchpredictions).option("checkpointLocation", "/delta/events/_checkpoints/etl-from-json").start()
```